# How to fix "No property [repositoryMethod] found for type [entity]!" when am i using a repository of an inherited entity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to set up a Spring Data Jpa repository for an entity that inherits from another entity.

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.6 with Spring Data Jpa. I already researched the problem and looked at the documentation, but the cases I found, although similar, none showed very well how to handle repositories for classes when we have entity inheritance.

Here I have the main class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    // Getters and setters omitted
}
```

And here the class that inherits from Person:

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
public class Driver extends Person   {

    private String vehicleModel;

    // Getters and setters omitted
}
```

So I created a filter to use in the repository:

```
public class DriverFilter {

    private String vehicleModel;

    // Getters and setters omitted
}
```

After I created the DriverQueries interface:

```
public interface DriverQueries {

    public Page<Driver> filter(DriverFilter filter, Pageable pageable);

}
```

And then I made its implementation:

```
public class DriverImpl implements DriverQueries {

    @Override
    public Page<Driver> filter(DriverFilter filter, Pageable pageable) {
        // code omitted
    }

}
```

I create the base repository:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface People<T extends Person> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
}
```

And finally, I create the repository for the inherited class:

```
@Repository
public interface Drivers extends People<Driver>, DriverQueries {

}
```

But when I run the program, I have the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property filter found for type Driver!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:382)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:324)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:293)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:276)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:250)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:380)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:381)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:93)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:78)
    ... 103 common frames omitted
```

If I create a repository for a normal class, following the same logic as the previous one, everything works perfectly.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: There are restrictions on how to create a custom repository. Please refer to the [official document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior).

Comment: You cannot use class which is not a property of @Entity defined in repository. To workaround i recommend you to create query which spead your filter property in single types and invoke it in default method which will accept your filter parameter or use `JpaSpecificationExecutor` it is really comfortable interface for filtering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error disappears if we assigned to the class **DriverImpl** the correct name by analogy with it parent (**DriverQueries**) - **DriverQueriesImpl**. In this case, the inherited class shall be called as the parent plus the suffix **Impl**.

Spring is strict on this.